# Delete an user in firebase auth with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

in my angular and firebase app I have an administrator, I want the administrator to be able to delete users from firebase auth, at that moment I have the email of all users, how can I do this through email? I only found this code but it doesn't work.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using the client-side SDKs (such as the JavaScript SDK) for Firebase Authentication, a user can only access and delete their own account. That is by design, as anything else would be a significant security risk.

Firebase does provide so-called Admin SDKs for use in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. Since these Admin SDKs run in trusted environments, they support a broader set of operations, like [deleting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) or [deactivating](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) any user in the project based on their UID.

But the Admin SDKs can only be used on trusted environments. They can't be included in the client-side application, such as in your Angular app.

This means you'll typically have to take a two-stepped approach:

1. Create a custom API/server-side endpoint (such as a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)) that uses the Admin SDK to delete a user you specify. In this code you'll want to ensure that the call comes from a trusted user, for example by hard-coding the UIDs that are allowed to make such calls.
2. Then [call this endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) from your application code.

Comment: Hello friend, in principle thank you very much for your answer, I have never carried out this operation and I am a little lost, could you attach me an example on which to base myself?
A greeting.

Comment: I included links to all the relevant documentation in my answer.